# Python : What's the error here ? Output keeps on generating try again

Tags: python

Output keeps on generating "try again." Whats the error here?

```
import random

x = int(input("guess a number between 0 and 10:   \n"))
y = random.randint(0,10)
n = "try again"
while n == "try again":
    if y == x:
        print("congradulations\n")
        break;
    else:
        input("try again\n")
```

Comment: Just calling `input("try again\n")` doesn't do anything to change `y`, `x`, or `n`, so `n == "try again"` will always be true, and `y == x` will always be false, so you'll just loop forever.

Comment: As a side note, if I were mechapsychic, or whatever the term is for being able to read a computer's mind, I'd be a bit annoyed that you cheated and asked me to guess your number before you'd even picked it. :)

Answer (score 3):

You loop for as long as `n == "try again"`. Since nothing ever changes `n`, that's forever.

You break out of the loop if `y == x`. But, since nothing ever changes either `y` or `x`, if that wasn't true the first time, it'll never be true, so you'll never break out of the loop.

You probably wanted to store the result in `x`, just like you do for the first `input`:

```
n = "try again"
while n == "try again":
               if y == x:
                    print("congradulations\n")
                    break;
               else:
                    x = int(input("try again\n"))
```

Now, instead of ignoring the user's retries, you'll actually test them to see if they're the right answer.

---

But, while we're at it, you can simplify this quite a bit. First, `n` never changes, so it's useless; you can just loop `while True:`

```
while True:    
   if y == x:
        print("congradulations\n")
        break;
   else:
        x = int(input("try again\n"))
```

---

Or you can just move the `y == x` check into the `while`loop:

```
while y != x:
    x = int(input("try again\n"))
print("congradulations\n")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import random
x = int(input("guess a number between 0 and 10:   \n"))
y = random.randint(0,10)
n = "try again"
while x != y:
   x = int(input('try again'))
else:
   print('congratulations!')
```

Or:

```
import random
x = int(input("guess a number between 0 and 10:   \n"))
y = random.randint(0,10)
n = "try again"
var = True
while var:
   if x != y:
      x = int(input('try again: '))
   else:
      print('congratulations!')
      var = False
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you missed to store the value of input into x in the **else** block.And i removed the condition check in while as you're trying to make it an infinite loop till the condition is correct.

Hope this helps..!!

```
x = int(input("guess a number between 0 and 10:   \n"))
y = random.randint(0,10)
while True:
   if y == x:
        print("Congratulations !! \n")
        break;
   else:
        x = int(input("Try Again\n"))
```